# Sybase code has has where clause: where a & b=c

Tags: sybase

I have a code below:

select id,role,unit
from user_id i,user_rol r,unit u
where unit_grp_catg_map_c & ib_unit_grp_catg_c = ib_unit_grp_catg_c

Can somebody explain me what is & and how it works?
I cannot find on the internet

Answer (score 0):

& stands for bitwise AND operation, [here](http://infocenter.sybase.com/archive/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.sqlug/html/sqlug/sqlug20.htm) you have details.